# How can I query by parent's field in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

What I need is, querying the products by its' categories' locale.

```
Product
  .find({
        'category.locale' : "en"})
```

But it is not possible. Where am I wrong?

My Product schema:

```
var ProductSchema = new Schema({
  code: {type : String, default : '', trim : true},
  category: {type : Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'Category'}
})
```

Comment: Can you paste your schema definition? Does it use references or nested documents?

Answer (score 3):

In your Product schema, category contains a reference in the form of an [object id](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/).

It's just an _id, so no locale is stored with the category in the product.

There are no joins in MongoDB.
One solution could be to find all categories separately that match locale='en', then use them as a filter on the products query.

This docs page has more details: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html